# Differences between questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

***Why*** is this question:

*"Can anybody recomend me a good documentation to learn how to use Jacoco?
I tried the Jacoco documentation, but it seems a little lengthy and I'm in a rush."* (-4 votes)

***different*** to this one:

*"Is there a good book or tutorial for setting up and using Clojure for beginners?"* (7 votes)

in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Links to the questions? I'd like to delete, er, I mean, look them over.

Comment: BTW, that's "CLuence", not "Clojure". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741224/good-documentation-for-learning-clucene

Comment: The CLuence one is closed  which would be the correct thing to do rather than down vote. The other were is it a link is needed

Comment: The other one was asked (and closed) by me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neither question is on topic on this site.  Perhaps the other question was older, back when the standards weren't quite as strict.  Perhaps a number of people decided to upvote it despite the fact that it violates the site's standards (either because they disagree with those standards, or because they were unaware of them).

Regardless of how many votes any given question has, you should not ask product/tool/book recommendation questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The older was closed over a year ago - albeit 2 1/2 years after been asked

Comment: @Mark There you go; the question was asked a long time ago; before these guidelines were in place.  That's also likely where they accumulated many of its upvotes.